# Error in applying Username Token scenario to Proxy WSO2 ESB

Tags: ws-security, wso2, rampart, wso2-esb

When applying security scenario 1 to a Proxy in wso2 esb , I get the following errors , but only when the Respond mediator is reached.

```
> TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-03-23 12:52:05,418] DEBUG
> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator} -  Start : Send
> mediator {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator} TID: [0]
> [ESB] [2015-03-23 12:52:05,419] DEBUG
> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator} -  Sending
> response message using implicit message properties.. Sending To:
> http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous SOAPAction: 
> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator} TID: [0] [ESB]
> [2015-03-23 12:52:05,511] ERROR
> {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} - 
> Content-Type:text/xml;charset=UTF-8,Date:Mon, 23 Mar 2015 10:52:02
> GMT,Server:WSO2 Carbon Server,Transfer-Encoding:chunked,<?xml
> version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope
> xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
> xmlns:prod="http://za.co.pepkor/product_service/"><soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
> soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"><wsu:Timestamp
> xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
> wsu:Id="Timestamp-1"><wsu:Created>2015-03-23T10:52:05.507Z</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires>2015-03-23T10:57:05.507Z</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><prod:productSearchResp>
> <productDetails><noItemFound>No item in
> Ackerman's</noItemFound></productDetails><productDetails><productID>1452168</productID><productName>PUMPS</productName><productSize>7</productSize><productColour>ORANGE</productColour><productType>SHOE</productType><sourceID>SHC</sourceID></productDetails><productDetails><productID>1124596</productID><productName>REEBOK_SNEAKERS</productName><productSize>7</productSize><productColour>BROWN</productColour><productType>SHOES</productType><sourceID>SHC</sourceID></productDetails><productDetails><productID>1123456</productID><productName>NIKE_SHIRTS</productName><productSize>7</productSize><productColour>RED</productColour><productType>SHIRT</productType><sourceID>SHC</sourceID></productDetails>
> </prod:productSearchResp></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> Unexpected
> error sending message back {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}
> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: No user value in the rampart configuration
> policy    at
> org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartSender.invoke(RampartSender.java:76)
>   at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)  at
> org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)  at
> org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)    at
> org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:426)  at
> org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:163)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:321)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:94)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AnonymousListMediator.mediate(AnonymousListMediator.java:30)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.config.xml.SwitchCase.mediate(SwitchCase.java:66)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.SwitchMediator.mediate(SwitchMediator.java:123)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.aggregator.AggregateMediator.completeAggregate(AggregateMediator.java:419)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.aggregator.AggregateMediator.mediate(AggregateMediator.java:314)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:196)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.aggregator.AggregateMediator.completeAggregate(AggregateMediator.java:419)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.aggregator.AggregateMediator.mediate(AggregateMediator.java:314)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
>   at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.Target.mediate(Target.java:106)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.splitter.IterateMediator.mediate(IterateMediator.java:146)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:160)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:261)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:488)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:170)
>   at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:225)
>   at
> org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> org.apache.rampart.RampartException: No user value in the rampart
> configuration policy  at
> org.apache.rampart.builder.BindingBuilder.addUsernameToken(BindingBuilder.java:212)
>   at
> org.apache.rampart.builder.TransportBindingBuilder.build(TransportBindingBuilder.java:95)
>   at org.apache.rampart.MessageBuilder.build(MessageBuilder.java:140)
>   at
> org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartSender.invoke(RampartSender.java:65)
>   ... 46 more
```

This is of course using the default policies. I tried editing the policy as follows (soap11binding level) :

```
<rampart:RampartConfig xmlns:rampart="http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy">
            <rampart:user>admin</rampart:user>
            <rampart:timestampPrecisionInMilliseconds>true</rampart:timestampPrecisionInMilliseconds>
            <rampart:timestampTTL>300</rampart:timestampTTL>
            <rampart:timestampMaxSkew>300</rampart:timestampMaxSkew>
            <rampart:timestampStrict>false</rampart:timestampStrict>
            <rampart:tokenStoreClass>org.wso2.carbon.security.mypwhandler.PWCBHandler</rampart:tokenStoreClass>
            <rampart:nonceLifeTime>300</rampart:nonceLifeTime>
         </rampart:RampartConfig>
```

Where PWCBHandler =

package org.wso2.carbon.security.mypwhandler;

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException;

import org.apache.ws.security.WSPasswordCallback;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager;

public class PWCBHandler implements CallbackHandler {

    private String all;

    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException,
            UnsupportedCallbackException {

        for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
            WSPasswordCallback pwcb = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[i];
            int usage = pwcb.getUsage();
            if (usage == WSPasswordCallback.USERNAME_TOKEN_UNKNOWN) {
                // verify uT password
                if ("admin".equals(pwcb.getIdentifier())
                        && "admin".equals(pwcb.getPassword())) {
                    return;
                }
            }
```

When I use the above handler , I get the following error:

> AxisFault: No password supplied by the callback handler for the user :
>   "admin"

Please assist me with this. I suspect it could be the service chaining aspect that might be causing the issue.

---

Other things I've tried :

Apply the above as a custom scenario policy , why does includes the keystore/trusted keystore option even though there is NO encryption taking place???

Another thing is why the default SecurityTokenStore is all commented out in the source code??? I cannot hit the above SecurityTokenStore  in remote debug...

---

Proxy :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="Product_Search_Proxy"
       transports="https"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target outSequence="productSearchHandler">
      <inSequence>
         <switch source="$trp:Content-Type">
            <case regex="text/xml;charset=UTF-8">
               <property name="CallType" value="SOAP" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
               <log level="custom">
                  <property name="Soap request read ..." value="sending..."/>
               </log>
               <log level="full" category="DEBUG" separator="____:::::____"/>
               <clone>
                  <target sequence="ackProductSearchRq"/>
                  <target sequence="shcProductSearchRq"/>
               </clone>
            </case>
            <case regex="application/json">
               <property name="CallType" value="REST" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
               <log level="custom">
                  <property name="REST or API request read ..." value="sending..."/>
               </log>
               <property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
               <log level="full" category="DEBUG" separator="____:::::____"/>
               <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                         name="name"
                         expression="//productSearch/productName/text()"
                         scope="default"
                         type="STRING"/>
               <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                         name="size"
                         expression="//productSearch/productSize/text()"
                         scope="default"
                         type="STRING"/>
               <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                         name="colour"
                         expression="//productSearch/productColour/text()"
                         scope="default"
                         type="STRING"/>
               <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                  <format>
                     <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                                       xmlns:prod="http://za.co.pepkor/product_service/">
                        <soapenv:Body>
                           <prod:productSearchReq>
                              <productName xmlns="">$1</productName>
                              <productSize xmlns="">$2</productSize>
                              <productColour xmlns="">$3</productColour>
                           </prod:productSearchReq>
                        </soapenv:Body>
                     </soapenv:Envelope>
                  </format>
                  <args>
                     <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                          evaluator="xml"
                          expression="$ctx:name"/>
                     <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                          evaluator="xml"
                          expression="$ctx:size"/>
                     <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                          evaluator="xml"
                          expression="$ctx:colour"/>
                  </args>
               </payloadFactory>
               <clone>
                  <target sequence="ackProductSearchRq"/>
                  <target sequence="shcProductSearchRq"/>
               </clone>
            </case>
            <default/>
         </switch>
      </inSequence>
      <faultSequence/>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL key="conf:/service_definitions/PepKorProductSearch.wsdl"/>
   <parameter name="ScenarioID">scenario1</parameter>
   <enableSec/>
   <policy key="conf:/repository/axis2/service-groups/Product_Search_Proxy/services/Product_Search_Proxy/policies/UTOverTransport"/>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the service runs on the axis 2 engine , going into the axis2.xml file in wso2esb-4.8.1\repository\conf\axis2\ , we see that in the Phases section(the phases represent the "flow" that proxies/services will run through") specifically the  <  phaseOrder type="OutFlow"  > section (which would correspond to the "outSequence" of the proxies) just after the    <  phase name="MessageOut"/  > , it performs the  <  phase name="Security"/  >  (which would correspond to the security policy of the proxy). So this is where the error is thrown and confirms with the above observation and error log

```
<phaseOrder type="OutFlow">
        <!-- Handlers related to unified-endpoint component are added to the UEPPhase -->
        <phase name="UEPPhase" />
        <!--      user can add his own phases to this area  -->
        <phase name="RMPhase"/>
        <phase name="MUPhase"/>
        <phase name="OpPhase"/>
        <phase name="OperationOutPhase"/>
        <!--system predefined phase-->
        <!--these phase will run irrespective of the service-->
        <phase name="PolicyDetermination"/>
        <phase name="PTSecurityOutPhase">
        <handler name="RelaySecuirtyMessageBuilderDispatchandler"
                     class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelaySecuirtyMessageBuilderDispatchandler"/>
        </phase>
        <phase name="PTCacheOutPhase">
             <handler name="CacheMessageBuilderDispatchandler"
                     class="org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.handler.CacheMessageBuilderDispatchandler"/>
        </phase>
        <phase name="MessageOut"/>
        <phase name="Security"/>
        <phase name="MsgOutObservation"/>
    </phaseOrder>
```

So we need to assert that the response for this specific proxy must be executed in a non-secured manner.( Communication between the back end is secured already using mutual SSL).

We can write a new module and plug it with ESB's module section( see https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Working+with+Modules )   where this module can be used to either skip the <  phase name="Security"/  > or apply an empty policy just before the <  phase name="Security"/  >. This modular way is the best approach since we can engage “NoSecurity” module only for our desired proxy/services.

```
Steps:

1.  In developer studio , created a module as described in (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Writing+an+Axis2+Module):

        Handler Logic:
        Note that following 2 uses requires the following OutFlow phaseOrder
        <OutFlow>
                 :
            <NoSecurity/>
            <Security/>
                 :
        </OutFlow>

        // To apply the bottom(getPolicy) empty policy for security phase...
            InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(getPolicy().getBytes());
            Policy policy = PolicyEngine.getPolicy(stream);
            if (policy != null) {
            messageContext.setProperty("rampartOutPolicy", policy);
            }
            return InvocationResponse.CONTINUE;

        // To skip the <security> phase when <noSecurity> is reached..
            msgContext.setCurrentHandlerIndex(msgContext.getCurrentHandlerIndex()+ 2);
            return InvocationResponse.CONTINUE;
```

{

```
private String getPolicy() {

        return "<wsp:Policy wsu:Id=\"emptyPolicy\" xmlns:wsp=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy\" "
                + "xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\">"
                + "<wsp:ExactlyOne><wsp:All><sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy\">"
                + "<wsp:Policy></wsp:Policy></sp:TransportBinding></wsp:All></wsp:ExactlyOne></wsp:Policy>";
}
```

}

```
2. Upload module to ESB (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Uploading+a+Module)

3. Engage module on a SERVICE LEVEL (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Module+Engagement+for+Service)

4. Re-tested = SUCCESS !
```

Answer (score 1):

You have confused the use of the CallbackHandler. It is used to provide the plaintext password that a [Validator](https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/apidocs/org/apache/wss4j/dom/validate/Validator.html) implementation will later validate the submitted password against, not to provide you with the opportunity to validate the password yourself.

Your code should resemble

```
if ("admin".equals(pwcb.getIdentifier()) {
    pwcb.setPassword("admin");
    return;
}
```

If you really do want to perform the validation yourself, please see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29200298/3696510)

Comment: Ok cool thanks, but I don't specifically want to do the validation myself , I just want the policy to work. Does the UT authentication only take place once during invocation by the client? And if so , why is the error only getting thrown once the response is about to be sent back to the client? The response message is valid and contains the timestamp.